# XPages: another unexplainable message

Tags: java, xpages

As a follow-up of my earlier question (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426222/xpages-can-someone-shed-some-light-on-these-messages/31436438)), here's one more interesting case. Sometimes, quite random, the following error pops up:

```
16/07/15 10:00: Exception Thrown
com.ibm.xsp.acl.NoAccessSignal
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.checkAccess(NotesContext.java:1726)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.serverProcessSignedResource(NotesContext.java:999)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.setSignerSessionRights(NotesContext.java:956)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:407)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:218)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.Application.loadClass(Application.java:708)
    at com.ibm.xsp.library.ApplicationFacesClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationFacesClassLoader.java:54)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.getClassForPageName(CompiledPageDriver.java:169)
    at com.ibm.xsp.page.compiled.CompiledPageDriver.loadPage(CompiledPageDriver.java:61)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:499)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.createViewRoot(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:567)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doCreateView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:142)
    at com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerEx.createView(ViewHandlerEx.java:90)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:251)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:160)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:576)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:853)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:796)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:565)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

The user is logged in, has all permissions, does nothing out of the ordinary, might have done exactly the same action many times in a row (while testing, opening and saving documents, etc.) and then suddenly the error occurs. Our application is a strange one: multiple active XPages in several windows or iframes, and their data are kept "in memory".

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

One line jumps out:

> at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.setSignerSessionRights(NotesContext.java:956)

Does the application use sessionAsSigner? If so, are all XPages-related design elements signed with the same ID? If not, ensure they are.

I'm not sure what the latest symptoms of that are, but in earlier releases it caused crashes.

Comment: Thanks. Nope, sessionAsSigner isn't used as far as I can tell. I resigned the application, just to be sure. Testing...